# How to cast parsed response from Model to a local variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I still like to call myself a novice when it comes to parsing a JSON response into a model class for usage. I have a certain JSON response which I have converted into a Model using one of those websites that does all the hard work. However, I repeatedly keep getting errors saying `type 'LoginModel' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'` when I make the API Call. Here is the response followed by the code:

The JSON response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "access_token": "*********",
        "role": 0,
        "id": 000,
        "lat": "0.0",
        "lng": "0.0",
        "radius": 200,
        "department": "IIIII",
        "approval": 1
    }
}
```

This here is the Model class:

```
class LoginModel {
  Data? data;

  LoginModel({this.data});

  LoginModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    data = json['data'] != null ? Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String? accessToken;
  int? role;
  int? id;
  String? lat;
  String? lng;
  int? radius;
  String? department;
  int? approval;

  Data(
      {this.accessToken,
      this.role,
      this.id,
      this.lat,
      this.lng,
      this.radius,
      this.department,
      this.approval});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    accessToken = json['access_token'];
    role = json['role'];
    id = json['id'];
    lat = json['lat'];
    lng = json['lng'];
    radius = json['radius'];
    department = json['department'];
    approval = json['approval'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['access_token'] = this.accessToken;
    data['role'] = this.role;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['lat'] = this.lat;
    data['lng'] = this.lng;
    data['radius'] = this.radius;
    data['department'] = this.department;
    data['approval'] = this.approval;
    return data;
  }
}
```

The class where I get the error:

```
class LoginController with ChangeNotifier {
  NetworkServices networkServices = NetworkServices();
  Map<String, dynamic> _loginResponse = {};    //I would like to store the parsed response into this variable for local use

  Map<String, dynamic> get loginResponse {
    return _loginResponse;
  }

  Future<void> login(dynamic data, BuildContext context) async {
    networkServices
        .postLoginRequest(ApiUrl.loginUrl, data, context)
        .then((value) {
      _loginResponse =
          LoginModel.fromJson(value['data']) as Map<String, dynamic>; //I'm pretty sure this is what I've done wrong

      print('SUCCESS: $_loginResponse');
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      // Loader(false);
      print('ERRROR: $error');       //This is where the error gets printed after it comes from the NetworkServices class where the API Call is made
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Network Class where the API gets called:

```
class NetworkServices {
  Future<dynamic> postLoginRequest(
      String url, dynamic data, BuildContext context) async {
    var jsonResponse;

    try {
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
          body: json.encode(data),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 30));
      jsonResponse = returnResponse(response);
      print('FROM NETWORK: $jsonResponse');

    } on SocketException {
      Flushbar(
        leftBarIndicatorColor: Colors.red,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.warning, color: Colors.white),
        message: 'Ooops!!! Something went wrong',
      ).show(context);
    }
    return jsonResponse;
  }

  

  dynamic returnResponse(http.Response response) {
    if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 300) {
      dynamic jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      return jsonResponse;
    } else if (response.statusCode >= 400 || response.statusCode == 404) {
      return 'An Error Occured';
    } else if (response.statusCode >= 404) {
      return 'Invalid Request';
    } else {
      return 'Error Occured While Communicating with Servers!!! Please try again later';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problems:

1. You are casting the `LoginModel` object returned from `LoginModel.fromJson(...)` as a `Map<String, dynamic>` instead of casting `value['data']` as `Map<String, dynamic>.`
2. You are also assigning the `LoginModel.fromJson(...)` to a variable of type `Map<String, dynamic>`, `_loginResponse`.

### Solution:

Change this line of code:

```dart
_loginResponse = LoginModel.fromJson(value['data']) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

to this:

```dart
_loginResponse = value['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

### Update:

In other to store the login information in the `LoginModel`, you need to make the following to the `LoginController` class:

1. Make the `_loginResponse` variable a `LoginModel` instead of a `Map<String, dynamic>`
2. Make the `loginResponse` getter return a `LoginModel` object instead of a `Map<String, dynamic>`
3. Cast `value['data']` to a `Map<String, dynamic>` and pass it into `LoginModel.fromJson(...)`

Your updated `LoginController` class will be:

```dart
class LoginController with ChangeNotifier {
  NetworkServices networkServices = NetworkServices();
  LoginModel _loginResponse = LoginModel();    

  LoginModel get loginResponse {
    return _loginResponse;
  }

  Future<void> login(dynamic data, BuildContext context) async {
    networkServices
        .postLoginRequest(ApiUrl.loginUrl, data, context)
        .then((value) {
      _loginResponse =
          LoginModel.fromJson(value['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>); 

      print('SUCCESS: $_loginResponse');
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      // Loader(false);
      print('ERRROR: $error');    
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I get when I try doing what you suggested A value of type 'LoginModel' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Comment: @coolhack7 I've updated the answer with the solution to this error.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, then this solution will have nothing to do with the Model Class. I'm actually more used to working without models and was looking for ways to learn how to parse JSON response using Models.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a way to store the parsed data in the `LoginModel`

Comment: Now that my question is answered, I would like to know if working without models is alright or not. If not, then why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251159/discussion-between-victor-eronmosele-and-coolhack7).